# Hide cells with password in jupyter notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I would like to know if it is possible to hide code cells in jupyter with a password. I've looked into it but couldn't find an straightforward way...

The idea is to have an exercise with the solution hidden below and provide access to the solution by giving a password.

Does anyone know of such thing?

Thanks!